# Can't see 'Attachment' option to a discussion in Discussion Board in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, discussion-board, attachments

I can't find a option in the ribbon for attaching a document/file to a discussion post in SharePoint 2013, either while creating a new discussion or Editing an existing one.

I know while we have focus on the `Body` field, we get multiple options like Upload file, Video and Audio and Picture... But all of them basically embed the files/documents into the body Rich-text. We can't view them as separate attachment files.

I have done a migration of Discussions from an external system to SharePoint 2013 using my custom tool. There i was able to attach documents(using Server side APIs) to discussions and those documents are viewed under Attachments field.(see the screenshot below)

[image]

**Question :** Is there some Configuration setting from UI or Powershell which enables the `Attachment` option on the ribbon ?

*Enabling the Attachments option under the Advanced Settings doesn't help.*

**UPDATE :**
In the view screen for the above(Edit) screenshot, i see an extra `View Properties` link also.
[image]

Comment: Is this an out of the box NewForm or did you customize it in SPD?

Comment: Mike, this is the OOTB Edit form.

Answer (score 1):

I mean its not OOTB, but you can execute the javascript function **UploadAttachment();** in EditForm.

If you want the **Attach File** Button in the ribbon you have to add a custom action

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="DiscussionAttachmentAction"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    RegistrationId="108"
    RegistrationType="List"
    Title="Re-Add an Attachment Button to Discussion Boards">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.Controls._children">
          <Button Id="DiscussionAttachmentButton"
            Command="AttachFileDB"
            Image16by16="/_layouts/15/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png?rev=23" Image16by16Top="-235" Image16by16Left="-235"
            Image32by32="/_layouts/15/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=23" Image32by32Top="-409" Image32by32Left="-409"
            LabelText="$Resources:core,cui_ButAttachFile;"
            ToolTipTitle="$Resources:core,cui_ButAttachFile;"
            ToolTipDescription="$Resources:core,cui_STT_ButAttachFile;"
            TemplateAlias="o2" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="AttachFileDB"
          CommandAction="javascript: UploadAttachment();" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```